# TypeScript - assigning array containing object reference

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I'm trying to assign an array to an object that contains an object which is not yet defined, and I don't really understand why it doesn't work. I thought objects in JavaScript are passed by reference, but it stays undefined in this case.
I'm calling a method like this:

```
this.myField = new InputField(...)
.withRevalidateOtherFields([this.otherField]);

this.otherField = new InputField(...);
console.log(this.myField.otherFieldsForRevalidation); // <-- [undefined]
```

The console output shows that the assigned field is still undefined, although it should have been passed by reference and the reference contains a valid object at that point.

The method assigns the parameter to the private field:

```
  public withRevalidateOtherFields(fields: InputField[]): this {
    this.otherFieldsForRevalidation = fields;
    return this;
}
```

Of course, I could call the method only after all fields point to a valid object, but this would make the code more complicated. Any ideas why it doesn't work like that?

Comment: Maybe oversimplified: You have put a reference to `this.otherField` inside the array for myField => `([this.otherField])`. But then you create a new reference and overwrite the existing reference by setting the field `this.otherField = new InputField(...);`, but that does not change the reference inside the array.

Comment: Ok that makes sense, is there an elegant way to fix that?

Comment: Sure. The simplest solution is to assign `this.otherField` first. Another solution is to assign an empty array first and after assigning `this.otherField`, push it into that array.

Comment: that would require the code to be further scattered, I'd rather pass a function as parameter that just returns the array.

Comment: Also an option, indeed. Using a delegate to return the current data.